PassportJS login problem with failureRedirect: '/auth/login'
I have a project where I am making a login system with passport.
I use nodejs and mysql. What happens is when i enter info and press login, it just failureRedirect: '/auth/login' without any logs.
Route file
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const passport = require('passport');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const db = require('../models');
const User = require('../models').User; // Import the User model

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.email);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (email, done) => {
  try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: email } });
      if (user) {
          done(null, user);
      } else {
          done(null, false);
      }
  } catch (err) {
      done(err, null);
  }
});


passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  async (email, password, done) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: email } });
      console.log('User:', user); // Log retrieved user object

      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false);
      }

      const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.EncryptedPassword);
      console.log('Password Match:', passwordMatch); // Log comparison result

      if (passwordMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return done(err, false);
    }
  }
));

router.get('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('login', { title: 'SY&FK', user: req.user });
  });

  router.post('/login/password',
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/auth/login', failureMessage: true }),
  function(req, res) {
    console.log("authenticate");
    console.log(err);
    console.log(user);
    console.log(info);
    res.redirect('/');
  });


router.get('/signup', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('signup', { title: 'SY&FK', user: req.user });
});

router.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { firstname, lastname, phone, address, zip, city, email, password } = req.body;

    // Check for missing fields
    const missingFields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'phone', 'address', 'zip', 'city', 'email', 'password']
      .filter(field => !req.body[field]);

    if (missingFields.length > 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Missing required fields', missingFields });
    }

    // Generate a random salt
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10); // Use bcrypt.genSalt for secure random salt

    // Hash the password using bcrypt with the generated salt
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    const newUser = await db.User.create({
      firstname,
      lastname,
      phone,
      address,
      zip,
      city,
      email,
      EncryptedPassword: hashedPassword,
      // Do not store plain text salt in the database
      Salt: salt,
      RoleID: 1,
    });

    res.redirect('/auth/login'); // Or your desired redirection
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in signup route:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});

App.js relevant
const { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
var db = require("./models");
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('express-flash');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

app.use(session({
  secret: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(passport.authenticate('session'));
app.use(flash());

app.use('/auth', authRouter);

Login.ejs relevant text
<form action="/auth/login/password" method="POST">
    <div class="row gy-3 gy-md-4 overflow-hidden">
        <div class="col-12">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="navn@eksempel.com" required>
            <label for="email" class="form-label">Epost</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Passord"
                   required>
            <label for="password" class="form-label">Passord</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
                <label class="form-check-label text-secondary" for="remember_me">
                    Hold meg innlogget
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="d-grid">
                <button class="btn bsb-btn-xl btn-primary" type="submit">Logg inn</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

Tried many different versions of the passport implementation.
